# Should each radius client have its own key?

Tags: authentication, cisco, radius

If I have many Cisco switches connected to Windows radius, should I assign a different key to each switch? Is it a best practice? If I leave the key same on every host, it would ease my deployment.

Comment: Usually you assign each entity its own authentication. Obviously using the same key makes all the switches vulnerable at once when its compromised.

Comment: Remember the advice about not using the same password for all your accounts, like your bank and twitter? Like that, only much, much more important.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, yes you should definitely. Especially if this is on a production network even more specifically if it's a customers production network.

It may "ease your deployment" but it wouldn't help at **all** if the network was breached. Please use different keys for each Radius client, it's not even a "best practice" it is purely common sense.

As Schroeder has stated it's the same thing with using different passwords for different accounts; you're *only* harming yourself by using the same "password". It may save you time *now* but it *adds time* to the aftermath of a breach.